# Warning message when I add bidders (Spotx and Aol)

Tags: prebid.js

I'm trying to use prebid.js for video ads.
I used your example codes, and try to add bidders.
When I add spotx and aol as bidder, it shows warning message below.
"Prebid WARNING: 
    video1 is a video ad unit
    containing bidders that don't support video: spotx.
    This bidder won't fetch demand."
"Prebid WARNING: 
    video1 is a video ad unit
    containing bidders that don't support video: spotx.
    This bidder won't fetch demand."

I tried to download prebid.js with select bidder adapter.
However I couldn't find Spotx when I can find spotx in your bidders param page.
And even I downloaded prebid.js with Aol selected, it shows same warning message.

```
var videoAdUnit = {
                code: 'video1',
                mediaTypes: {
                    video: {
                        playerSize: [640, 480],
                        context: 'instream'
                    }
                },
                bids: [{
                    bidder: 'appnexus',
                    params: {
                        placementId: 13232361, // Add your own placement id here
                        video: {
                            skipppable: true,
                            playback_method: ['auto_play_sound_off']
                        }
                    }
                },{
                    bidder: 'spotx',
                    params: {
                        channel_id: 234646,
                        video_slot: 'contentElement',
                        slot:  'content'
                    }
                },{
                    bidder: 'aol',
                    params: {
                        placement: 1160795,
                        video_slot: 'video1',
                        slot:  'admaru_video_o'
                    }
                }]
            };
```

Answer (score 0):

They haven't released it yet integrated with Prebid, but you can access it from here https://github.com/prebid/Prebid.js/blob/057fa954a10afdb3cf51e1acaa55133a0b53f85c/modules/spotxBidAdapter.js

Download the code locally, then build Prebid with spotx in modules directory. So something like `gulp build --modules=spotxBidAdapter,dfpAdServerVideo,aolBidAdapter`

Make sure you include all the modules you want to use.